# How to provide text direction on ckeditor5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react, ckeditor5-plugin

Is there any config setting using which i can initialize my ckeditor with a specific language direction like rtl or ltr?

I tried to find solution in ckeditor5 documentation but could't find any, while going through it i can see that u need to provide abberiviation for a language and then it accordingly manages the direction of the text.